# AngularStrap modal inside modal

Tags: modal-dialog, angular-strap

Whit AngularStrap modal directive, is it possible to open another modal dialog inside/within a modal box?

What I'm trying to do is, open a modal box that contains a list of items to select. Inside this modal box there's a button to open another modal box to do a search on the item list.
But I got error when click on the button inside the modal box. Is there something I missed?

Here is a code sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeroxp/t3yv94d1/

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal01.tpl.html">
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>fruits <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-bs-modal="modalSearch" data-template="modal02.tpl.html">search</button></th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-click="itemSelected(item)"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal02.tpl.html">
    <input type="text" class="form-contorl"/>
</script>
```